# Can I have two spectral assassins at once?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got the power to summon a spectral assassin from the dark brotherhood quest-line, but can I use my spectral assassin once, wait 24 hours, then do it again and have 2 spectral assassins? Also, can I have a spectral assassin as well as my current (human) follower.

I have read the [Elder Scrolls wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Spectral_Assassin) and it says the following:

> After being summoned, he will follow the Dragonborn around, no matter where they may be, until they summon another Familiar, Atronach, Raise Zombie, or when he is defeated.

Does this mean I can have 2 spectral assasins at once, since casting the power again is not summoning Familiars, Astronaches or raise zombies, or the assassin being defeated. Or does it fail due to too many followers.

Is it possible to get multiple spectral assassin this way, and can I get the assassins with a human follower?

Comment: I expect the Spectral Assassin is classed as a Familiar, so summoning a new one will likely just unsummon the first one, but I'm not sure. That said, have you tried it at all? Sounds like it wouldn't be too hard to test if you already have the ability.

Comment: like @JonK said, I'm pretty sure the reason the Assassin goes away if you call another Familiar/Atronach/Undead creature is because he takes up that slot.  I can't keep mine alive long enough to test, but I only call him when I'm losing a fight.

Comment: "It is possible to have two Spectral Assassins; leave the original Assassin in the Ragged Flagon and he will no longer follow the player. Then, one should return some time later, and the Assassin will no longer be '(Insert Character Name)'s Spectral Assassin', but rather 'Talk to Spectral Assassin', similar to a regular NPC. Now, he can be looted upon death and pickpocketed. Then, the player can summon a second Spectral Assassin. However, the original Assassin will not follow the player anymore, and will remain in the Flagon." From the page. Seems to imply your method would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First of all you cannot use the 'summon Assassin' power within 24 hours of use.

2) Second of all if your assassin is alive after 24 hours and you use the power again it will simply disappear from the position it was standing and appear in another position close to you. Thats it.

I am sorry to crush your dream of having an assassin army, but that's how the game works. I know this because i myself have tried it multiple times.

However, you can get the assassin along with a human follower and a dog and  if you have anyone else following you which is related to a particular mission.Cheers.

Comment: And if you have the [twin souls perk](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjuration#Skill_Perks) you can also summon the assassin AND another creature (e.g. a Frost Atronach), but still not two spectral assassins